# How to rename an SVN branch through all revisions (history)?

Tags: svn, git-svn

How can I rename a branch in SVN through all revisions so that it looks like it always had the new name when checking the log?
I understand that there may be no SVN client command for this, but is there anything I could do on the server?

The reason for this is that I'd like to move to **git** and **git-svn clone** doesn't like a branch name like "*Fix 1, 2 and 3*" (I guess because of the comma).

Answer (score 2):

svn move last_branch new_branch

Comment: This is equivalent to `svn copy` + `svn delete`, so it won't do the trick for older versions.

Comment: It won't affect, but as result will not have wrongly named Git reference. Just tried with git-svn and SmartGit: both work with the resulting repository. And this approach is less danerous.

Comment: This was also my first idea and I even did this too. However, when running git-svn clone, the older revisions will still use the old name 'last_branch' thus the errors would still be there. So I don't see the benefit in this.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you may use "svnadmin dump"  + edit dump (with own script or have a look at svndumptool.py) + "svnadmin load" combination. But this approach is not recommended, because you can get broken svn:mergeinfo and potentially may corrupt your repository.

So would also vote for "svn move" approach.